# How can I synchronize my progress on two different devices?

Tags: google-play-games, sky-force-reloaded

I'm playing Skyforce both on my phone and on my tablet (mostly on my phone because it has a pen) but my progress isn't being synchronized. The game always is in an older state on the tablet. Is this a known problem of Skyforce or Google Play or is there a way to synchronize them?

Comment: As far as I know skyforce isn't using the snapshot feature of Google play games, but instead using their own saved games logic. Infinite dreams would need to implement some sort of cross device saving features. I had this problem with regular Skyforce, which is why I only play reloaded on a single device.

Comment: Do you know of any sources which mention this? If you know could you please point them out in an answer.

Comment: I work on Google Play Games, and the snapshot tables on the phone are empty, so they aren't using our feature. But even if they were, it's up to the game developer to decide what to store. Anyway, whatever they are using, is home grown or another service. There are some comments around the web that the cloud save they are using transfers progress, but not stars. http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=288639&page=12

Comment: Thanks Matt. I can vote and select your answer if you write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue with the Google Play Games cloud save feature, but Infinite Dream's implementation of cloud save (if it's even an issue, since this is probably working as Infinite Dreams intended). Regardless of the technology that Infinite Dreams is using to store cloud saves, it's up to the developer to decide what data is stored in the cloud save, and it looks like they chose to sync ship upgrades, but not stars (http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=288639&page=12).